# jquery unbind click event on img element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I couldn't bind a click event after an unbind. Can anyone solve this problem? Here is a sample of my code:

```
if(condition for radio button)
  jQuery('#txtEffectiveBeginDate').
      next('.ui-datepicker-trigger').
      unbind('click').
      css({ 'opacity': .50 }).
      css('cursor', 'text');
else
  jQuery('#txtEffectiveBeginDate').
      next('.ui-datepicker-trigger').
      bind('click').
      css({ 'opacity': 1 }).
      css('cursor', 'pointer');
```

Comment: What would `bind('click')` do?

Comment: You have to pass a callback function to `.bind()` (it doesn't automatically re-bind whatever was bound previously).

Comment: A better way would be to check the radio button state in the handler.

Comment: hint: `unbind('click')` makes jQuery literally forget all attached click handlers.

Comment: Hint2: The jQuery UI datepicker has built in disable functionality.